# Change the content of textblock text inside the control template of the button..?

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, controls

I have a button for which control template is stackpanel. Inside the stackpanel there is textblock.My doubt is how to change Text of that Text Block dynamically.?

```
<Button x:Name="Animate" Width="auto" Height="25" Click="Button_Click_2" Content="Close">
                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>                        
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock x:Name="AnimateTextBlock" Text="Actions" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="14"></TextBlock>
                            <Image Source="/HB.EmployeeInfo;component/Images/Actions.png"  Width="20" Height="20"></Image>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Button.Template>
            </Button>
```

I want to change AnimateTextBlock Text Dynamically..??How to do this.?

Comment: which way you tried? dynamically in code or in xaml?

Answer (score 0):

add this line in your button action code:

```
x.Text = "Text Box content";
```

ex:

```
private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
x.Text = "Text Box content";
  }
```

take a look on that artical to learn about button controls :

http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Button-Controls-in-Silverlight-2-Beta-1.aspx

Comment: when you want your text to be changed?

Comment: And one more doubt do you how to change the Image source inside the Control template stack panel dynamically..??

Comment: my code is working fine! you just need to add that code in your button   click event.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23235/discussion-between-arpit-and-siva)